# Laravel 4 very very slow how to check what is slowdown?

Tags: performance, laravel-4

i installed fresh copy of laravel4 , than installed Laravel 4 starter kit site:

[laravelcp](https://github.com/gcphost/laravelcp)

My site run so slow between pages(loads):

[image]

969ms , and i have 950-1.5ms this very bad.

I using localhost **wamp**.

What i tryed:

1. optimize wamp.
2. i changed from localhost to 127.0.0.1 at database.php
3. i did both php artisan optimize and php artisan optimize --force

Also when i install fresh copy of laravel i have 130-160ms.

When i install other [starter kit](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) i have 320-400ms.

Anyway i am laravel 4 newbie , how can i check what makes the load time ?

maybe its some package or something.

Comment: Is there any diffence if you call a blank page? You can try to create a route returning a simple string and call it to see the difference.

Comment: In the starter kit or fresh laravel 4 ? in the starter kit its the same,fresh laravel i have 130-150 ms

Comment: Regular pages with no frontend are 200ms. Frontend with local js and CSS is about 600ms after artisan optimize. I think some caching of mysql calls will help. Will stay tuned for more suggestions.

Comment: I've found that the larger the controller file is the more loading time, there are 2 or 3 controllers with a dozen or more functions. When the controllers are reduced (say to one for testing) the speeds are under 100ms for an average query

Comment: So how can i create a big app with laravel , when he can't handle big code ? 400ms for me it's alot either. should i search for other framework for big project?

Comment: My stock laravel is 80ms. I got a no dom laravelcp down to 95 to 115ms. Dom loaded at 350ms. Having git issues but ill post a new update tonight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have debug=true in app/config/app.php (or a local environment's config) you will not be cacheing anything. If you aren't using the cache then it makes sense that your load times with apc vs file cacheing would be similar.

First, try setting debug to false globally, or for your local environment. Then run php artisan optimize after cacheing is disabled.

Test your speeds using a direct route (no controller, simply return "some string"; from the routes.php route for the homepage.

Try returning the same string from a controller action. Map this action to the same route for the homepage and compare. On my local setup I see about a 10ms difference.

If that doesn't speed your app up then try installing the profiler suggested (or the one I prefer: https://packagist.org/packages/sebklaus/profiler) and see what is taking the most time to run. You can enable either profiler so that they run even when debug mode is false.

Another alternative is not to worry about local speed or speed during development and get laravel sped up once your app is working as you want.

Here are some tips to help you with the post-development optimization: [Optimizing for production with Laravel 4](http://www.lutro.me/posts/optimizing-for-production-with-laravel-4)

Comment: Debug off and optimized saves some time. Nkt much. I found large controllers caused a lot of lag. Reduced the file sizes and  number of calls got it to a reasonable speed

Answer (score 4):

For simple debugging, there's a cool debugbar you can install and profile your app with:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

It'll show you how long laravel takes to boot up and gives you some other debugging and profiling options.

Also, it looks like you tried running 'php artisan optimize'.  Just in case you didn't try it yet, make sure to turn off debug mode before optimizing.  This will turn off lots of debugging features, but it will drastically reduce the amount of files Laravel needs to include.

Comment: thanks , i will check, also you know why when i change the cache to apc at cache.php , i have the same load time? if i had 30ms with file, it will be the same with apc , why?(i have apc installed)

Comment: I'm still a noob at PHP and I've only been doing Laravel for a few months, so I can't help with specifics on APC.  When I've used other caching frameworks (for Java) before, half the battle has been just diagnosing to see if your caching solution is even working.  Perhaps there's logging you can turn up to look at this?